# How to run vim bufdo in parallel

Tags: vim, parallel-processing

I would like to run a costly vim command for all my buffers in vim, as far as I can tell, these commands are run synchronously. Is there a way to have them execute in parallel?

Comment: AFAIK the new "job" feature only works with external commands so I would answer *no*.

Comment: Well, you could write a function that started one external Vim job for every buffer, and execute the commands there. You would have to be careful with details like swap files and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vim 7 or a lower version, parallel processing is not supported.
This has been implemented in vim8 ([see What’s new in Vim 8](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2017/01/practical-vim-revised-for-vim-8/)).
I suggest you to look a `:help job`